# Generar otra pagina con pm2 en mi servidor Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost

Tags: mysql, nodejs, typescript, vue.js, pm2

tengo una página con un eCommerce con el front desarrollado en vue y el back en TS la cual se está corriendo en pm2 en el lado del servidor. Ahora el problema surge cuando quiero generar otro ecommerce en otro dominio, ya cambie el puerto en el cual se comunican el front y el back, al puerto ya lo habilite en el firewall, y tambien cambie la base de datos en el back y migre las que ya tenia generadas en la que anda correctamente.
Esta es la configuración de mi ormconfig.js donde lo único que cambia es la DB.

```
module.exports = {
    type: 'mysql',
    host: process.env.DBHOST || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.DBPORT || 3306,
    username: process.env.DBUSER || 'root',
    password: process.env.DBPASS || '',
    database: process.env.DBSCHEMA || 'onlysoft',
    entities: ['dist/entities/**/*.js'],
    logging: true,
    synchronize: false
};
```

Y al iniciar el pm2 me arroja este error:
[image]

Especificamente el error seria `Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: Parece que la variable d ambiente `DBPASS ` no esta recibiendo ningún valor en pm2 y esta pasando el valor del corto circuito que es un string vacio `''`. Declaraste bien esa variable?